# how do I add an arbitrary byte value onto the end of a string? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, byte

in JavaScript, how do I add an arbitrary byte value onto the end of a string?  I'm trying to construct an array which contains both ASCII and binary data, for passing to a remote server.  I tried String.fromCharCode() but that only seems to work for bytes from 0x00 to 0x7f inclusive - larger byte values get turned into two-byte characters (which all makes sense now that I think about it).

Thanks in advance -

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var myString = "Hello world";
myString += "\x21";
alert(myString);
```

Or, for a less canonical string that nonetheless demonstrates the range:

```
var myString = "Hello world";
myString += "\xE9";
alert(myString);
```